# Como predeterminar un html con express.static?

Tags: html, express

Mi problema es que tengo varios archivos html en la carpeta 'public' y quiero que cuando entren en la direccion '/' me cargue un bienvenido.html pero en lugar de eso me carga otro (*index.html*).
¿Cómo puedo configurarlo para que me cargue el *bienvenido.html*?

Estoy usando:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

Answer (score 0):

cuando usas `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` lo que estás haciendo es utilizar el servicio de archivos estáticos de Express, según la [página oficial](https://expressjs.com/es/starter/static-files.html) puedes definir esta ruta:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Y acceder a los diferentes archivos dentro de ella:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/imagen.jpg
```

En tu ejemplo, si en el navegador pones: `http://localhost:<tu puerto>/bienvenido.html` debería renderizar la página *bienvenido.html*.

Si lo anterior está correcto, define una ruta específica para esto:

```
router.get('/', auth, function(req, res) {
    res.render('bienvenido');
});
```

Con eso ya podrás cargar directamente `http://localhost:3000/` y renderizar la página que deseas.

Para utilizar render mira el [siguiente enlace](https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/).